# How do i send the view back to ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.5

I am new to Laravel. I have created a form and when the user clicks on submit button I make an ajax call and save data to the table in a database. Everything until here is working fine. After the data is saved I am making another ajax call to display recently saved information. Now, when I try to render the data in view I get an exception
 `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\n    \"message\": \"Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\userinfo\\\\resources\\\\views\\\\ajax\\\\show.blade.php)`

if i perform the same action without using ajax it works fine.

**Route:**

```
//route for ajax call to display user information
Route::get('/userinfo','ClientsController@ajaxShow');
```

**Controller**

```
public function ajaxShow(Client $client){
        $userID=Input::get('id');
        $user=Client::find($userID);
        $msg='Your data is saved.Go to listing page to see.';
        $returnHtml=view('ajax.show',compact('msg'))->with('user',$user)->render();
        return $returnHtml;
    }
```

**Model**

```
class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'name',
        'prov_id',
        'telephone',
        'postal',
        'salary'
    ];
    use SoftDeletes;

    //client/users table can have many provinces.
    public function province(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Province','prov_id');
    }
    protected $table='users';
    protected $dates=['deleted_at'];
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="alert alert-primary">
        {{$msg}}<br/>
</div>
<div>
    {{$user}}

</div>

<div class="info_wrapper">
    Name:{{$user->name}}<br/>
    Province :{{$user->prov_id->name}}<br/>
    Telephone :{{$user->telephone}}<br/>
    Postal:{{$user->postal}}<br/>
    Salary:{{$user->salary}}
</div>
```

When I perform the same thing without using ajax it works perfectly.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/testuserinfo','ClientsController@testShow');
```

**Controller**

```
public function testShow(Client $client){
        $user=Client::find(293);
        $msg='Your data is saved.Go to listing page to see.';
        return view('clientinfo.show',compact('user','msg'));
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="alert alert-primary">
        {{$msg}}<br/>
    </div>

    <div class="info_wrapper">
        Name:{{$user->name}}<br/>
        Province :{{$user->province->name}}<br/>
        Telephone :{{$user->telephone}}<br/>
        Postal:{{$user->postal}}<br/>
        Salary:{{$user->salary}}
    </div>
```

**Ajax**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers:{
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

//when the user clicks on save button call ajax to save user information
    $('#frmSaveUser').on('submit',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

        var clientName=$.trim($("input[name='name']").val());
        var province=$("input[name='prov_id']").val();//$("#_province").val();
        var tel=$.trim($("input[name='telephone']").val());
        var postal=$.trim($("input[name='postal']").val());
        var salary=$.trim($("input[name='salary']").val());


       if(validateInputFields(clientName,province,tel,postal,salary)){
           $.ajax({
               method:'POST',
               url:$(this).attr('action'),
               data:$(this).serialize(), //get all the input field values
               dataType:'json'})
               .done(function(res){
                   //todo
                  // console.log('res:'+JSON.stringify(res));
                   showUserInformation(res.id)
               })
               .fail(function(res){
                   if(res.status!==422){
                       //alert('Error saving your work.');
                       $('#frmSaveUser').find('.error').remove();//remove any previous errors displayed
                       console.log(res);
                       return;
                   }
                   else{

                       $('#frmSaveUser').find('.error').remove();
                       //parse the response text and and get the errors
                       var errors=JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                       // console.log(errors);
                       for(var fieldName in errors['errors']){
                           //console.log(errors['errors'][fieldName]);
                           var inputField=$('#frmSaveUser').find('[name='+fieldName+']').parent(); // find the parent element of the input that has error
                           //if there are more than one error message create a list by concatenating errors in msg var.
                           var msg='<ul>';
                           for(var i=0;i<errors['errors'][fieldName].length;i++ ){
                               msg+='<li>'+errors['errors'][fieldName][i]+'</li>';
                           }
                           msg+='</ul>';

                           inputField.after().append('<div class="error">'+msg+'</div>');//display the error message below the field.
                       }

                   }
               });//end of ajax method
       }//end of if statement
    });//end of form submit function
```

**Function called from ajax above from done() function**

```
/*Function to display recently inserted user's information*/
    function showUserInformation(id){
        console.log('id:'+id);
        $.ajax({
            method:'GET',
            url:'./userinfo',
            data:{id:id}
        })
        .done(function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(data);
            $('.container-fluid').empty().html(data);
        })
        .fail(function(res){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        })//end of ajax method
    }
```

I would highly appreciate if anyone could help me solve this issue. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: have you checked input:all() in the function itself. $request = Request::all();  
        try to dd($request) in the controller itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make another Ajax call after you save information. Just return new user information as JSON from controller when you save it. Then you can parse JSON in AJAX .done part and display where you need.

Comment: Thank you, Darius, for you advise. I did follow your advise but I am still curious why the things worked without ajax. I mean same $user passed to view is accessible without ajax and not accessible with ajax. I want to understand the flow as well. If you could make it more clear i would be very thankful.